# SQL Server: Unique Composite Key that looks order

Tags: sql-server, constraints, composite-primary-key

I created a small test table with 2 integer columns `pkId1` and `pkId2`. I set the primary key as a composite that includes both columns, (`pkId1` is first, then `pkId2`).

Now I inserted some values, in the following order: `(1,1)`, `(1,2)`, `(2,1)` and `(2,2)`. I was expecting  `(2,1)` to fail, but it did not. How can I force it to fail ?

I could check it into my application, but I want to do it in SQL side.
Also, I thought about using a stored procedure, but I would like to know if there a setting to set for the composite key in the designer of the table.

## Edit

Order of `pkId1` and `pkId2` do matter. For example, if (2,1) was already in the table, (1,2) should not be accepted. The reason for this is because the row represents a link between two entities. Thus, it should be read there is a link from 2 to 1 for (2,1) and a link from 1 to 2 for (1,2).

As for same value in both columns (1,1), (2,2), etc., they are accepted, because they are a special case.

Comment: Each column is a distinct entity, so value `(1,2)` is different from `(2,1)`. You need to implement a trigger for such functionality.

Comment: Sorry, why should it fail? If you want `pkId1` unique, create a unique key/index just on that column

Comment: @Charlieface It should fail because OP wants (2, 1) to be considered the same as (1, 2)

Comment: Perhaps simply create a check constraint on the table to force pkId1 <= pk2. That would reject (2, 1) for a slightly different reason but with less complexity and less "duplication" in your DDL.

Comment: @Charlieface Indeed, I know the behavior sql has now is correct. I, however, would like the insert to fail. As I said, I know it is a simple check in a stored procedure, I just wanted to know if there was a setting that ensures that insert would fail.

Comment: Nope - there is no setting. Order matters.

Comment: Do `pkid1` and `pkid2` have to be unique even in the same column?

Comment: @SMor That wouldn't work, since the orders matter. I will update the question, but basically, this table represents a link between two items. If i have (1,2), it means item 1 points to item 2, and vice-versa. I wanted to block the fact that you could have two different links between 2 same items (between the same item it would be correct, special case). Therefore, coding pk1 <= pk2 wouldn't work, because I would loose the order.

Comment: @Charlieface no they are not unique within the same column

Comment: @RegularNormalDayGuy Yes, it will work. Try it. Admittedly, it is based on a simple trick - that your PK tuple always has the first column as the lowest in the tuple. (1,2) is accepted, (2,1) is rejected. another (1,2) is also reject by standard PK uniqueness. But it does mean that (2,1) is rejected even when (1,2) does not exist.

Comment: And you might want to consider what really happens storage-wise when you persist a column. Might be negligible here but still worth considering in a general sense.

Comment: @SMor but let's say I want to add (2,1) when there is nothing. I would not work since pk1 > pk2. In my case, (1,2) is not the same as (2,1)

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is in the same row? I.e. can I put in (2,2)?

Comment: Yes, (2,2) is allowed.

Comment: @SMor I think I've solved the (2,1) problem below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is create an PERSISTED column

**Example**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [pkId1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [pkId2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [pkuc]  AS (case when [pkId1]<[pkId2] 
                     then concat([pkId1],'-',[pkId2]) 
                     else concat([pkId2],'-',[pkId1]) 
                end) PERSISTED NOT NULL UNIQUE
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Test**

```
Insert Into [dbo].[TestTable] (pkId1,pkId2) values (1,2)
Insert Into [dbo].[TestTable] (pkId1,pkId2) values (2,1)

Select * from [dbo].[TestTable]
```

**Updated Table**

```
pkId1   pkId2   pkuc
1       2       1-2
```

Comment: Then it makes sense to build PK on "pkuc". Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Two relatively simple options present themselves.

---

**1. A check constraint and "instead of" trigger**

If we create a constraint `pkId1 <= pkId2`, then the requirement can be satisfied, as noted in [SMor's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601738/sql-server-unique-composite-key-that-looks-order#comment115988532_65601738). However, the problem is that this also blocks an insert of (2,1).

To solve this, we create an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the table that swaps the values:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER TrgINS ON dbo.Table
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT dbo.Table (pkId1, pkId2)
SELECT
  IIF(pkId1 > pkId2, pkId2, pkId1),
  IIF(pkId1 > pkId2, pkId1, pkId2)
FROM inserted;

GO
```

---

**2.  An indexed view to enforce the constraint**

We create an indexed view on the table with the values swapped. The unique constraint on the view itself enforces the requirement, so a single insert of (2,1) is not blocked, a further insert of either (2,1) or (1,2) is blocked:

```sql
CREATE VIEW vwTableUnique
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS

SELECT
  IIF(pkId1 > pkId2, pkId2, pkId1) AS pkId1,
  IIF(pkId1 > pkId2, pkId1, pkId2) AS pkId2
FROM dbo.Table;

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_vwTableUnique ON dbo.Table (pkId1, pkId2);

GO
```